# restrict drag and drop of image from file system in parsys of aem page

Tags: aem

How to restrict Users from dragging and dropping an image which exists outside of the DAM (i.e. desktop or other mapped drive) into the parsys of my aem page.
I am using the OOTB image component provided by aem using the html5smatimage widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a copy of the foundation image component to your project, and add a property for the *html5smartimage* widget in the dialog `allowUpload="{Boolean}false"` which should stop the upload of local images to your dialog. Refer below screenshot.

[image]